# Prevent shifting/moving of child divs as parent div width reduces to 0

Tags: html, css

I am applying `white-space: nowrap;` on my div as I shrink its width to 0. This gives me what I am after in that as it shrinks, everything just stays in place and disappears. This works until the div gets very thin, then the input fields jump beneath the labels.

A label and input field are set up in the following manner:

```
<div class="k-edit-label" style="margin-top: -6px;">
    <label for="someInput">Some Input</label>
</div>
<div data-container-for="someInput" class="k-edit-field" id="someInputContainer">
    <textarea id="someInput" name="someInput" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:someInput" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

And what happens is shown in this image:

[image]

And every label/input pair is wrapped in a div, that I apply `white-space:nowrap;` to as I shrink its width to 0. Without doing the white-space:nowrap, the inputs jump below the labels much sooner. With the nowrap, they do what I want until the div wrapper gets very thin.

However, what I am wanting is for the piece of the image that says 'What I want to happen.' I just want the labels and inputs to slide out of view with no shifting or jumping below anything.

Oh yes, my CSS for the edit-label and edit-field:

```
.k-edit-label {
    width: 25% !important;
}

.k-edit-field {
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left !important;
    width: 65% !important;
}
```

Any help on figuring out how to style this to prevent shifting of contents when reducing the width of the parent div would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put the `white-space: nowrap` to the container element.

Comment: It is in the main container, that wraps them all. Does each label/input need its own container with white-space: nowrap?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
1. `display: inline-block` instead of floating approach
2. add `overflow:hidden` in case you'll have additional content along with textarea inside this div.

```
.k-edit-label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25% !important;
}

.k-edit-field {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 65% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```